# Finding windows computer hardware model from sniffing

Tags: windows, sniffing, fingerprint

Do any of you know a way to find out a computer specific model (eg: Lenovo ThinkPad e490, Dell XPS 13 9380) running windows os, passively, only by sniffing the data the computer sends and receives?

Comment: Downvoters, please explain what's wrong with the question and how it can be improved. Just leaving a downvote isn't helpful at all.

Comment: In the modern world where everyone is screaming about privacy and *browser* fingerprinting, why exactly do you think a computer would be screaming out its full system specifications to anyone and everything that talks to it? What purpose would it serve? What benefit would it have? Moreover, what do you think the downsides would be from a privacy perspective? Which is worse, a browser identifying you, or your computer essentially sending out its entire hardware fingerprint down to the CPU serial number? Not the downvoter, just trying to provoke some thought.

Comment: It's a possible security issue for Windows users with hackers who try to get their tentacles in everywhere: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMGvz.png. I'm also not a downvoter, just another interested reader who has posted on this topic.

Comment: To all the naysayers: [A Passive Technique for Fingerprinting Wireless Devices with Wired-side Observations](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IgX8_WC8OT8QTelAIKKugH0lqCwblD3C/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0):

Check out e.g. `nmap`, it can find out lots of pieces of information about the *software* running on a machine. On the same network, you can find out the make of the netwok card by it's MAC address.

As comments above imply (and the documentation warns) running this against a machine can be taken as an hostile act.